# Parceler ZipException "duplicate entry"

Tags: android, parcelable, parceler

I'm building a project which has two classes (A and B) that both inherit from BaseClass. Both classes, A and B, have the annotation @Parceler. When I build it for a phone with OS ver 4.1.2 (API 16), it gives me this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.  
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:  
com/example/BaseClass$$PackageHelper.class
```

If I build it for a phone with Nougat, there are no problems.

I had read about using parcelsIndex, but Parceler doesn't support with the version I'm using - 1.1.8.

Are there any fixes for this problem?

Comment: If possible add problematic code.

Comment: @PravinDivraniya, i'm not sure what code is creating the problem. It seems more like having two Parcellable classes inheriting from a common Parcellable class is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the classes in different modules - this seemed to have caused it. While there are may be some solutions using `@ParcelClass` annotation (https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler/issues/225 ?), I simply moved them to the same module, and it's building fine now.

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused because you're using 2 dependencies for the same library, with different version of the dependency.

For your case, i need more data, but i'll give an example that seems to explain your issue : say your project uses library x, and library x uses the dependency :
`compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0"`

This is how your gradle looks like :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile "com.company.library_x:+"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0"
}
```

Here's the thing, since you're using the same dependency, `library_x` and you have collisions in the dependency, because you're importing version `23.4.0` and the library is using version `25.3.0`. When you build a project, all the dependencies are taken and 'downloaded', in this case, you've downloaded 2 versions of the same library and you have duplicated entries. You don't have a lot of options, but to use the same version `library_x` uses, which means in your case, build your project with the latest version.

Fyi, some more info : under `build->intermediates->exploded-aar->appcompat-v7->25.3.0->...class_of_the_error.class` you can actually see the value that caused the problem.

Comment: if that was the case, I would have seen errors as given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification, but I don't. Also, this problem occurs due to my own classes - not a library's. And that too only in Release builds. Anyway, it looks like it's due to referring to a Parcellable class in another module - I have just moved the classes to the same module. Thanks for your help though.